# Is it possible to cover only UDEV events with udev rules?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, automation, rules, udev

When I look at the output of `udevadm monitor` for an USB device, there are `KERNEL` and `UDEV` events.

Can I only address the `UDEV` events with a udev rule?

```
$ udevadm monitor | grep "mouse"

KERNEL[122.593013] add    /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-7/3-7:1.0/0003:1234:5678:0006/input/input12/mouse1 (input)
UDEV  [123.643263] add    /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-7/3-7:1.0/0003:1234:5678:0006/input/input12/mouse1 (input)
```

I've tried:

```
ACTION=="add" \
, SUBSYSTEM=="input" \
, UDEV=="mouse*" \
, ATTRS{idVendor}=="1234" \
, ATTRS{idProduct}=="5678" \
, RUN+="/usr/local/bin/do_something.sh"
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 (*Kernel:* `4.15.0-72-generic`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because udev events are emitted *as a result* of rule processing.

(That is why udev duplicates these events in the first place: they are sent out after rule processing completes, and they contain all the extra information that rules might have added.)

- If you want to make sure the rule won't run twice: That already won't happen. Rules are *only* triggered by 'kernel' events.
- If you need to access information that another rule adds: Make sure the filename of your custom .rules file is ordered after the ones you need. For example, if 70-foo.rules sets the necessary properties, put yours in 71-whatever.rules or 80-meh.rules.
- If you want to run an X11-related command, such as 'xinput' or 'xmodmap': Don't. Really, don't. Unless your CPU can teleport back through time, it's not going to work. See if the same setting can be achieved through /etc/X11/Xorg.conf instead.

  (Alternatively, write a tool that hooks into X11 events – example included below.)

---

Attachment: `x11-device-monitor.c`

```c
#if 0
src = $(MAKEFILE_LIST)
app = $(basename $(src))

$(app): LDLIBS = -lX11 -lXi
$(app): $(src)

define source
#endif

/* (c) 2018 Mantas Mikulėnas <grawity@gmail.com> */
/* Released under the MIT license <https://spdx.org/licenses/MIT> */
/* http://who-t.blogspot.com/2009/05/xi2-recipes-part-1.html */

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/extensions/XInput2.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    Display *d;
    Window rw;
    int xinput_op, foo;
    unsigned char mask[2] = {0};
    XIEventMask ximask;
    XEvent ev;
    XIHierarchyEvent *hev;

    d = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (!d)
        errx(1, "cannot open display");
    if (!XQueryExtension(d, "XInputExtension", &xinput_op, &foo, &foo))
        errx(1, "no XInput extension on display");
    rw = RootWindow(d, DefaultScreen(d));
    XISetMask(mask, XI_HierarchyChanged);
    ximask.mask = mask;
    ximask.mask_len = sizeof(mask);
    ximask.deviceid = XIAllDevices;
    XISelectEvents(d, rw, &ximask, 1);
    XFlush(d);
    for (;;) {
        XNextEvent(d, &ev);
        if (ev.type != GenericEvent)
            continue;
        /* XInput2 always uses extended events */
        /* http://who-t.blogspot.com/2009/07/xi2-and-xlib-cookies.html */
        if (ev.xcookie.extension != xinput_op)
            continue;
        if (ev.xcookie.evtype != XI_HierarchyChanged)
            continue;
        if (!XGetEventData(d, &ev.xcookie))
            continue;
        hev = ev.xcookie.data;
        if (!(hev->flags & XIDeviceEnabled))
            continue;
        warnx("device enabled");
        system("xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap");
        XFreeEventData(d, &ev.xcookie);
    }
}

#if 0
endef
#endif
```